# YQ/JQ special characters query convertor

Tags: bash, jq, yq

I am using yq together with jq and as I have learned you need to "escape" special characters in keys to quotes and brackets.
I would like to query the data using the pure dot syntax .cars.big-trucks but I was unable to find any tool that would do the conversion for me.

My ideal usage would be:

```
query=$(jq-query-convert ".cars.big-trucks")
yq -r $query cars.yaml
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Example yaml file:

```
%YAML 1.1
---

cars:
    big-trucks: 42
```

For jq users an example json would be:

```
{
 "cars": {
  "big-trucks": 42
 }
}
```

queried by

```
cat cars.json | jq "$q"
```

Comment: @Inian Question was edited, I added example files but also answered my question.

Comment: You need to use `jq '.cars."big-trucks"'` i.e. have the word with `-` under double quotes

Comment: I wasn't asking on how to escape the query string but rather a tool for it. I've wrote the python script and so far it's enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

Well I came up with this python3 one-liner that serves my intentions so far but if anyone know more robust solutions I am happy to accept it.

```
python3 -c 'from sys import argv; print("." + argv[1].replace(".", "\"][\"")[2:] + "\"]")' ".cars.big-trucks"
```

returns 
.["cars"]["big-trucks"]